# Crear una función en Javascript con un string de parametro como alert()

Tags: javascript

Lo que quiero hacer va de lo siguiente, estoy utilizando `Jquery` para hacer una `función` pero necesito hacer una función similar a la de alert("TEXTO"), o alert(TEXTO).

Mi función es la siguiente 
`$(".alert").html(CONTENIDO QUE ESTÁ ESPECIFICADO EN LA FUNCIÓN)`, vi una forma de hacerlo, pero antes de inicializar la función hay que especificar la variable como por ejemplo 
`

```
variable = "string"; 
customAlert(variable). $(".alert").html(variable)`
```

Comment: Algo asi http://kamranahmed.info/toast?

Comment: Saludos; coloca el código que tengas y apoyate en las opciones de negrillas, texto codigo, citas, etc que proporciona el editor/redacción de contenido. Y estructuras mejor tu planteamiento.

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo bien qué quieres decir con

> (CONTENIDO QUE ESTÁ ESPECIFICADO EN LA FUNCIÓN)

pero no necesitas **jQuery** para eso:

```js
function alerta(elemento, mensaje){
  try{
    elemento.innerHTML = mensaje;
  } catch(e) {
    alert(mensaje);
  }
}

alerta( document.getElementById("alert"), "mensaje importante ..." );
```

Sólo pasarle como argumentos a la función el elemento del **DOM** donde mostrar el '*alert*' y el *mensaje*.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var alerta = function(message) {
   alert($('#texto').val());
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="texto" value="nada"> <input type="button" onclick="alerta($('#texto').val())" value="send">
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        //Creo la función que voy a emplear para mostrar los mensajes
        jQuery.fn.alert = function(valor) { 
            $(this).html(valor); 
        };

        //Empleo la función en el botón cuando es presionado

        $('#boton1').on('click', function(){
            //Aqui es donde se produce la magia, puedes reemplazarlo donde desees como $('#otro_boton').alert('mensaje')
            $(this).alert("Este es mi primer mensaje");
        });
    });
</script>
```